# ImportError: No module named tensorflow_hub

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, machine-learning

Doing a Machine Learning model for Android using this [instruction](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5130220/Make-Your-Own-Image-Classifier-On-Android-Using-Te).

After I've put these lines into the Command line,

```
python retrain.py
--bottleneck_dir=/{directory_to_bottlenecks }/bottlenecks        
--how_many_training_steps 1000
--model_dir=/{directory_to_folder_you_saved_the_mobilenet}/mobileNet
--output_graph=/{directory_to_folder_you_want_to_save_the_model}/papa_graph.pb
--output_labels=/{directory}/papa_labels.txt
--image_dir /{directory_to_images_folder}
```

have an error, now.

> File "retrain.py", line 134, in 
>       import tensorflow_hub as hub ImportError: No module named tensorflow_hub

OS: macOS Catalina.

Did exactly the same things it is being said. No errors during the installations. I have checked if there was the tensorflow_hub folder at all. Yes.

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

Previously worked with Anaconda to install pip, Tensorflow... 
It doesn't see the folder. 
What is the best solution?

Comment: Does running python --version give you Python 3.6?

Comment: If not change `python retrain.py` to `python3 retrain.py`

Answer (score 0):

As [Dan-Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/839338/dan-dev) mentioned, the problem was about the python version. It's the 5th tutorial about Machine Learning for Android that doesn't work step-by-step.

Thanks to the new version of macOS Catalina - all previous modules and environments were displaced. So even after I've fixed this error, a lot of new problems appear:

> pip install tf-nightly-2.0-preview

Installation/Updating the tf-nightly doesn't work at all.
Moreover, after the Command-Line update:

> zsh: command not found: conda
>
> zsh: command not found: brew
>
> zsh: command not found: curl
>
> zsh: command not found: ruby
>
> zsh: command not found: gcc

Conclusion:

Problem #1 different version of Python, pip are being used by default.

Problem #2 too buggy macOS version of Catalina.